# Exercise 2.4.3. (Dimension shifting) from Weibel's Homological Algebra.

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, projective-module

$\newcommand{\F}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}$The following is an exercise from the book mentioned in the title:

> If $0 \to M \to P \to A \to 0$ is exact with $P$ projective (or $\F{F}$-acyclic), show that $\F{L}_{i}\F{F}(A) \cong \F{L}_{i - 1}\F{F}(M)$ for $i \ge 2$, and that $\F{L}_{1}\F{F}(A)$ is the kernel of $\F{F}(M) \to \F{F}(P)$. More generally, show that if
> \begin{equation*} 
>   0 \to M_{m} \to P_{m} \to P_{m - 1} \to \cdots \to P_{0} \to A \to 0
>  \end{equation*}
> is exact with $P_{i}$ projective (or $\F{F}$-acyclic), then $\F{L}_{i}\F{F}(A) \cong \F{L}_{i - m - 1}\F{F}(M_{m})$ for $i \ge m + 2$, and $\F{L}_{m + 1}\F{F}(A)$ is the kernel of $\F{F}(M_{m}) \to \F{F}(P_{m})$.
>
> **Conclude that if $P \to A$ is an $\F{F}$-acyclic resolution of $A$, then $\F{L}_{i}\F{F}(A) = H_{i}(\F{F}(P))$.**

(Notations: $\F{F}$ is a right exact functor and $\F{L}_{\ast}\F{F}$ are the left derived functors.)

I was able to do the first two parts under the assumption of $P_{\ast}$ being $\F{F}$-acyclic but I am having trouble showing the last part "Conclude that...".

### My thoughts

If I assume $P \to A$ to be a **projective** resolution, then for any $m$, I can form the exact sequence
$$0 \to \ker(d_{m}) \to P_{m} \to P_{m - 1} \to \cdots \to P_{0} \to A \to 0.$$
Moreover, I have a projective resolution of $\ker(d_{m})$ as
$$\cdots \to P_{m + 2} \to P_{m + 1} \to \ker(d_{m}) \to 0.$$
Using the definition of $\F{L}_{\ast}$, I can now compute $\F{L}_{\ast}\F{F}(M)$ in terms of $H_{\ast}(\F{F}(P)$). I haven't exactly worked out the indices to see if it matches, but my issue is that without assuming projectivity I don't see any way of solving it.

#### Sidenote

(Can be ignored by those wanting to answer the question.) In case any future readers are stuck in the first two parts, here's an outline:
First assume that we have
\begin{equation*} 
  0 \to M \to P \to A \to 0.
 \end{equation*}
For $i \ge 2$, we have the following segment from the associated long exact sequence
\begin{equation*} 
  \F{L}_{i}\F{F}(P) \to \F{L}_{i}\F{F}(A) \to \F{L}_{i - 1}\F{F}(M) \to \F{L}_{i - 1}\F{F}(P).
 \end{equation*}
Since $i - 1 \ge 1$ and $P$ is $\F{F}$-acyclic, we see that the two ends above are $0$. Thus, $\F{L}_{i}\F{F}(A) \cong \F{L}_{i - 1}\F{F}(M)$, as desired. Similarly work out $\F{L}_{1}\F{F}(A)$.

Now, assume that we have a general exact sequence as
\begin{equation*} 
  0 \to M_{m} \to P_{m} \xrightarrow{\varphi_{m}} P_{m - 1} \xrightarrow{\varphi_{m - 1}} \cdots \xrightarrow{\varphi_{1}} P_{0} \xrightarrow{\varphi_{0}} A \to 0.
 \end{equation*}
By breaking the sequence into short exact sequences as
\begin{align*} 
  0 \to \ker(\varphi_{m}) & \to P_{m} \to \im(\varphi_{m}) \to 0, \\
  0 \to \ker(\varphi_{m - 1}) & \to P_{m - 1} \to \im(\varphi_{m - 1}) \to 0, \\
  & \vdots \\
  0 \to \ker(\varphi_{1}) & \to P_{1} \to \im(\varphi_{1}) \to 0, \\
  0 \to \ker(\varphi_{0}) & \to P_{0} \to A \to 0,
 \end{align*}
we now inductively apply the previous part by noting that $\im(\varphi_{k}) = \ker(\varphi_{k - 1})$ and $\ker(\varphi_{m}) = M_{m}$.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. You seemed to have proven the result...

Comment: Hi @Roland: My issue is with the final sentence of the exercise. I have now boldened it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok sorry I misunderstood the question. Let $i\geq 0$ and put $P_{-1}=A$ and $P_{-2}=0$ so that what I write makes sense if $i=1$ or $i=0$.

Consider the resolution $$...\to P_{i+1}\to P_i\to P_{i-1}\to P_{i-2}\to...\to P_0\to A\to 0$$
and truncate :
$$...\to P_{i+1}\to P_i\to M_{i-1}\to 0$$
$$0\to M_{i-1}\to P_{i-1}\to P_{i-2}\to...\to P_0\to A\to 0$$
so you have $M_{i-1}=\ker(P_{i-1}\to P_{i-2})=\operatorname{coker}(P_{i+1}\to P_i)$.

Now, you have proven that $L_iF(A)=\ker(L_0F(M_{i-1})\to L_0F(P_{i-1}))=\ker(F(M_{i-1})\to F(P_{i-1}))$.

But since $F$ is right exact, you have $F(M_{i-1})=\operatorname{coker}(F(P_{i+1})\to F(P_i))=F(P_i)/\operatorname{im}(F(P_{i+1}\to P_i))$.

Thus $L_iF(A)=\ker(F(M_{i-1})\to F(P_{i-1}))=\ker(F(P_i)/\operatorname{im}(F(P_{i+1}\to P_i))\to F(P_{i-1}))=H_i(F(P_\bullet))$.

Comment: Is there a typo in your last line? The term $\ker(F(P_i)/\operatorname{im}\to F(P_{i-1}))$ doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I wrote im without precision for better readability, but it wasn't clearer apparently. I corrected.

Comment: I guessed that but I think the arrow and placement is still off. Do you mean $\ker(F(P_i) \to F(P_{i-1}))/\operatorname{im}(F(P_{i + 1}) \to F(P_i))$? In any case, it is clear what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: No the placement is correct, but this is the same thing.